# Set namespace manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a really complex rails application with few 'layers' based on user role:

1. Admin layer
2. Label layer
3. Band layer
4. Fan layer

Each layer / namespace has a bit different layout and options beeing rendered. Those differences are so big that i need to strongly separate each of them.

I could use a routing namespaces and put each layer under proper url namespace which would be `/admin`, `/label`, `/band`, `/fan` but i don't want it to be visible on frontend (in url) and route-based. However, the thing i would love in this solution would be a possibility to separate each application part controllers, models and views in layer sub-folders.

Proper layer can be determined by current_user role so it would be awsome if i would be able to set desired namespace manually in `application_controller` rather than using path patterns.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: I think you mean "programmatically" not Pragmatically. If so please correct and it will be better understood for others.

Comment: haha yeah, sorry, it was really stupid. In cause i'm not sure and i'm a bit confused right now, i'll use 'neutral' word ;) thanks

Comment: Anyway, I think it can be done. Try doing it yourself.

Comment: I don't even know how to start. I've searched a lot but without any luck. All the resources tells how to use namespaces with routing and i can't find anything in the API. That's why i've opened this question.

Comment: apart from having no idea how to implement it, i think it is a better idea to just implement what you have to do and afterwards refactor what you think it to be the best thing for you.

Comment: Can we see a difference between your different "roles"? Maybe it will be easier to understand your problem and find a solution

Comment: Well, the situation described in my question is a simplified version of a real problem. I'll try to demonstrate it on an example: Let's say we have a two user roles: `band_member` and a `fan`. Both of them can access `domain.com/bands/:band_id` but depending on user role, member or fan should see a completely different app part. For band, it should be a band managing app and for fan, just a band profile. And both should use the same URL, it's a client requirement.Please have in mind that it's just an example, in reality it's far more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

Here is an example with scopes and roles (with the warden gem)

```
scope module: lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.role } do
 resources :posts, :comments
end
```

More info about routing here : [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

This example does not handle the case when user isn't logged-in and the case where the module does not exists. I don't know if it is the right path to take, but it is a solution.

2)

The second idea I have is to not route through different modules, but to use [Exhibits](https://github.com/objects-on-rails/display-case) and the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

What I like about this idea is that it is more OO, but maybe less the "Rails way"